# Why is a surface in the $R^3$ approximated by a quadratic equation?

Tags: differential-geometry, surfaces

[image]

On the above, if there is a tangent plane, then is it best to approximate the surface $S$ by a linear equation? Why and how does one approximate the equation for $S$ by a quadratic one $Z=1/2(AX^2+BY^2)$? I cannot understand the motivations...

Comment: It looks like they are defining curvature on S. Think of a curve in $\mathbb R^2$, at each point $(x,y)$ of that curve, you can adjust a circle such that the curve is tangent to the circle. Once this is done, you can adjust the ratio of that circle in order to find the sphere that "best" fits the curve. This is useful to define curvature.

Comment: What do you mean by adjusting the ratio of that circle?

Comment: I mean the ratio of curvature, for instance if the curve is a straight line, it is clear that the circle that best fits this curve has infinite radius. I noticed that you posted another question, it is actually defined there, cheers

Answer (score 4):

Take a surface $S\subset{\mathbb R}^3$ and a point ${\bf p}\in S$. Then you can consider he tangent plane $T$ at ${\bf p}$ as $(x,y)$-plane and the surface normal at ${\bf p}$ as $z$-axis. In this way in the neighborhood of ${\bf p}$ the surface appears as graph $z=f(x,y)$ for a certain function $f$. Things are set up in such a way  that $$f(0,0)=0\>, \quad f_x(0,0)=0\>, f_y(0,0)=0\ .$$ These equations simply express that the point ${\bf p}$ has coordinates $(0,0,0)$ and that $T$ is the tangent plane to $S$ at ${\bf p}$. If we look at the Taylor expansion of $f$ at $(0,0)$ it therefore has the form
$$f(x,y)=ax^2 + 2bxy + cy^2+\ {\rm higher\ terms}\ .\tag{1}$$
Linear algebra then tells us that we can rotate the coordinate axes in the $(x,y)$-plane such that in $(1)$ no mixed term $2bxy$ appears. As a consequence  the second Taylor approximation of  $f$ can be written (in the new coordinates) as
$$z=Ax^2+By^2$$
with certain real constants $A$, $B$. Now that these preliminaries are out of the way the interesting differential geometry begins $\ldots$

Comment: On what basis can one set $f$ as you did? I mean how is it possible to set $f(0,0)=0$ $f_x(0,0)=0$ and such?

Comment: @Keith If you choose the origin and orientation of your coordinate axes judiciously, as done in this answer, those results are exactly what you get. For example, if you set the origin on the surface, then how can you _not_ have $f(0,0)=0$? If you previously chose some other origin and/or orientation, then perform a transformation of coordinates.